# How can i use jq to get specific data from a json response?

Tags: json, api, curl, response

I am using an API to get data, an example is the following:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"test1"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"test2"
      }
   ]
}
```

I would to use jq to only get the block where the name is 'test1' but sometimes 'test1' is under a different id like:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"test2"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"test1"
      }
   ]
}
```

The response i am trying to get using jq is

```
  {
     "id":*,
     "name":"test1"
  }
```

I have tried a few things with jq however i just receive errors.
How can i acheive this?

Comment: Please update your question and add the code demonstrating your best attempt at resolving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`select()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example28)

```
jq .data[] | select(.name=="test1")
```

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test1"
}
```

[JQPlay](https://jqplay.org/s/MLggd-y4jj)